# What's a really good pattern to extract logic from models and have the results persisted to the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been experimenting with different ways of structuring my app, and particularly with ActiveRecord-based models, looking into the notion of having a separate class whose results are saved as a single field. Now composition might have worked, but there's been a lot of discussion on whether its staying or not, so I was wondering what alternatives you might have.

Example:

```
class Gadget < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor: lights

end
```

Now, I would like the `lights` property to be 'managed' by a completely separate class:

```
class Lights

  def doSomething
  end

  def doSomethingElse
  end 

end
```

What's a good way of, say, proxying or delegating this logic out of the `ActiveRecord` model and into the `Lights` class in order to transparently store the results?

e.g. using an instance of the `Lights` class as the `lights` property - but that won't work, since there's no association, right?

e.g. use `method_missing` to push all requests out to the `lights` instance - but that won't work either, because it won't be persisted to the database.

Maybe it's not possible, but I'm interested in ways of persisting the results of logical operations. All suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like:

```
class Gadget < ActiveRecord::Base

  def lights
    @lights ||= Lights.new(self)
  end

end

class Lights
  attr_reader :root
  delegate :save, :save!, to: :root

  def initialize(root)
    @root = root
  end

  def doSomething
  end

  def doSomethingElse
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    #delegate all setters to root
    if method_name =~ /.*=$/
      root.send(method_name, *args, &block)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Thus you can do:

```
gadget = Gadget.new
#say gagdet has a name column
gadget.lights.name = 'foo'
gadget.lights.save
gadget.name #=> 'foo'
```

Still unsure why you need it but it should work

Comment: This looks quite neat, will run it shortly. The idea was that the property of the object could become an object in its own right outside of an active record association, and so on create/update, the property could simply deal with its own processing and save its state in the parent's model. There's a number of reasons for it outside of my own interest, which are around being able to swap out the logic transparently for the Light class - which could be doing all sorts of things - e.g. blinking, flashing, strobing - and saving its state in the parent without the parent having to care too much.

Comment: This works quite well - after a minor fix above. It'd be good to see if we can make this pattern work without having to stick too many delegates in (in this instance we have to delegate :save and :save! and this could get unwieldy.